# Why can I not initialize this NSArray With Objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsobject

I have an array containing objects of a custom-made class. However, on initialization the compiler gives me an error - `"Lexical or Preprocessor" Expected ':'`

```
interface myClass : NSObject
@property (readwrite, strong) NSString* name;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSString* home;
@property (readwrite, strong) Preference pref; // This is another custom class
-(id) initWithName:(NSString*) name home:(NSString*) home preference:(Preference) preference;
end

@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rowArray;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
...
...
...

- (void) initializeArray
{
    self.rowArray = @{
                      [[myClass alloc] initWithName:@"Harry" home:@"New York" preference :Acura],
                      [[myClass alloc] initWithName:@"Win" home:@"Seattle" preference :Toyota];
                    };
}
```

Can someone tell me just where I am messing up and why I'm getting this error?

Comment: There should be an @ symbol before interface. Or is that a copy and paste error?

Comment: New York and Seattle are not NSStrings.

Comment: lol... thanks. It's a re-typed sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Objective-C literal](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#container-literals) for an array is with square brackets,

`NSArray *anArray = @[obj1, obj2]`.

In the code you posted it is trying to make a Dictionary,

`NSDictionary *aDict = @{"key1" : obj1, @"key2" : obj2}`

so this is why it is saying it expects a `:`.

The line should read,

```
self.rowArray = @[
    [[myClass alloc] initWithName:@"Harry" home:"New York" preference :Acura],
    [[myClass alloc] initWithName:@"Win" home:"Seattle" preference :Toyota];
];
```

As others have pointed out the there are a few other errors with the code and those city names are not NSString's, but I guess this is just an example snippet.

Comment: That's it. Damn I need larger glasses. Thanks!